# How to Keep Open Kendo DropdownList on Item selection

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have KendoDropdownlist in web application

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 200px;" })
        .Name("cbStatusFilter" + i)
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataValueField("Id")
        .TemplateId("tpStatusFilter")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>)ViewData["statuses"])
         .Events(c => c.Select("cbFilter_Select").Close("cbFilter_Close"))
    )
```

it has templete as following

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="tpStatusFilter">
    <input type="checkbox" id="#= Name #" name="#= Name #" value="#= Id #" class="check-input-status" #=selected ? "checked" :"" # />
    <label for="#= Name #">#= Name #</label>
</script>
```

when use select item from dropdown i dropdown list gets close. but i want to keep it open and want to close when i click on some-other controls
How can i achieve it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but it based on knowledge of how JavaScript for the drop down is written.  If Kendo re-writes the JavaScript (doubtful at this point in time), this answer may not work.

If you look into the source code for the function, you will see that in the onChange event, the the Kendo drop-down code will toggle the visibility of the drop down items.  Knowing this, you can "trick" the code into doing what you want by adding a call to jQuery's .hide()`function.  See the call to`color.hide()` in the below snippet. Now, when the Kendo control onChange event fires, toggling the visibility will now show the list.

The control will automatically close the list when it looses focus, so you don't have to worry about that.

```
var color = $("#color").data("kendoDropDownList");
function onChange() {
      var value = $("#color").val();
      color.hide();
      $("#cap")
```

This code is based on http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index and has only been tested in Chrome.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 debugger;
 var data = [{
   text: "Black",
   value: "1"
 }, {
   text: "Orange",
   value: "2"
 }, {
   text: "Grey",
   value: "3"
 }];

 // create DropDownList from input HTML element
 var color = $("#color").kendoDropDownList({
   dataTextField: "text",
   dataValueField: "value",
   dataSource: data,
   index: 0,
   change: onChange
 });

 // create DropDownList from select HTML element
 $("#size").kendoDropDownList();

    // IMPORTANT
    // save pointer to actual kendo control.
    // This is required to make the call to the .hide() 
    // function work correctly.
 var color = $("#color").data("kendoDropDownList");

 color.select(0);
 var size = $("#size").data("kendoDropDownList");

 function onChange() {
   var value = $("#color").val();
   color.hide();
   $("#cap")
  .toggleClass("black-cap", value == 1)
  .toggleClass("orange-cap", value == 2)
  .toggleClass("grey-cap", value == 3);

 };

 $("#get").click(function() {
   alert('Thank you! Your Choice is:\n\nColor ID: ' + color.value() + ' and Size: ' + size.value());
 });

  });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index">
  <style>
    html {
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />

  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="example">
    <div id="cap-view" class="demo-section k-header">
      <h2>Customize your Kendo Cap</h2>
      <div id="cap" class="black-cap"></div>
      <div id="options">
        <h3>Cap Color</h3>
        <input id="color" value="1" />

        <h3>Cap Size</h3>
        <select id="size">
          <option>S - 6 3/4"</option>
          <option>M - 7 1/4"</option>
          <option>L - 7 1/8"</option>
          <option>XL - 7 5/8"</option>
        </select>

        <button class="k-button" id="get">Customize</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <style scoped>
      .demo-section {
        width: 460px;
        height: 300px;
      }
      .demo-section h2 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
      }
      #cap {
        float: left;
        width: 242px;
        height: 225px;
        margin: 20px 30px 30px 0;
        background-image: url('../content/web/dropdownlist/cap.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
      }
      .black-cap {
        background-position: 0 0;
      }
      .grey-cap {
        background-position: 0 -225px;
      }
      .orange-cap {
        background-position: 0 -450px;
      }
      #options {
        padding: 1px 0 30px 30px;
      }
      #options h3 {
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 25px 0 8px 0;
      }
      #get {
        margin-top: 25px;
      }
    </style>


  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the event counts::
I'm using kendo slightly different so you may need to modify it to fit the way you're using it.

```
<input id="dropdown" k-keepOpen/>
```

Then for the work::

```
$("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
keepOpen:$("#dropdown")[0].hasAttribute("k-keepOpen"),//this will turn it on and off by your element
preventCloseCnt:0,//this is used for managing the event
select:function(e){ this.preventCloseCnt=2;},//set the counter to bypass closing
close:function(e){
  if(this.keepOpen && this.preventCloseCnt >0 ){//now the next time something tries to close it will work ( unless it's a change )
  e.preventDefault();
  this.preventCloseCnt--;
  }
}
});
```